# Is there any way to install MS Office Shortcut Bar (from Office 2000) on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, shortcuts

While I am aware that Office 2000 is not compatible with Windows 10, I am attempting to see if there’s any trick to install a lone component called MS Office Shortcut Bar from Office 2000 on to Windows 10 64bit.

Those of you who might have used Office 2000 way back in late 90’s or early 2K would be familiar with this component called MS Office Shortcut Bar. A handy toolbar to create and launch your shortcuts. This feature was later permanently discontinued by Microsoft. I successfully installed it up till Windows 7 though.

When I attempt to install it from Office 2000 setup on Windows 10 64, it throws error while registering 4 DLLs
MSOLAP, MSMDCUBE, MSMDGRV & MSOLAPUI.  These get copied at C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\System\OLE DB\

```
Error 1904 Failed to register <filename>.DLL
```

I can ignore and continue but the resulting shortcut bar (though installs) fails to launch any shortcuts indeed.

I have tried to manually register these DLLs using regsvr32 invoked from SYSWOW64 but it does just nothing. The control returns to command prompt without any warning or error or anything whatsoever.

Does anyone know of any trick to make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would get it working (as likely APIs changed and so on). But did you look for alternatives like just attaching those shortcuts to the start menu or using something like launchy?

Comment: There's an alternative app called FreeBar on Sourceforge but it did not appeal to me much! Interestingly when I put a shortcut on MS Office Shortcut Bar its icon changes to 'Question Mark' but right click 'Open' works though single left click fails.